# Ant does not include generated class files to packaged jar, until I do a Project->Clean in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I ran into some strange behaviour that seems to be connected to Eclipse and it's way to refresh the workspace.

I'm using an Ant build file to create my class-files and to create a package from that class-file. This functionality is working fine.

This is the target doing the work:

```
    <target name="package" depends="compile,javaDoc">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyApplication.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" includes="**/*.class">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyApplication" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Now I want to add functionality to first clean the directories where the class-files and the jar file are beeing generated.

This is the target code:

```
<target name="clean" description="Removes all *.class and *.jar files. Also deletes the java doc files.">
<delete dir="${build.dir}" />
<delete dir="${dist.dir}" /></target>
```

This target also works fine.

Now I would like the package target **dependent on the clean target**, so that the folders are first cleaned before the packaging is beeing done.

This would look like this:

```
    <target name="package" depends="clean,compile,javaDoc">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyApplication.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" includes="**/*.class">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyApplication" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

The problem is, that this target does not include the generated class files into the jar. Even on the file system the generated class files are not displayed. Only **after I go to Project->Clean** in Eclipse and clean the project the class files become visible on the filesystem.

Any help is appreciated.

My compile target looks like this:

```
    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles the source file to the created directory.">
    <javac classpathref="classpath" srcdir="${dist.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" />
</target>
```

Comment: can you post your compile target?

Comment: sure - I added it at the end of the question

Comment: target clean, compile: delete directory "dist.dir" and after that please compile all files in "dist.dir"...

Comment: not entire sure what you mean

Comment: your clean target removes the source files. Your compile target tries to compile the deleted files and therefore does not produce any class files.

Comment: thx for the hint
actually the compile target was wrong and never created class-files. this was always done by eclipse.
I changed ${dist.dir} to ${src.dir} in the compile target. 
Now it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

fixing the error in the compile target worked.
That is the working version:

```
 <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles the source file to the created directory.">
<javac classpathref="classpath" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" /></target>
```